# Cpanel Domain name not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, whm, system-administration

i installed cpanel from  amazon marketplace on amazon server.
 installation completed successfully.
 i created a cpanel account from whm with some domain name.
 i am trying to run html file from public html.
  using domain name/file name 
  not working.

please give some suggestions
thanks
Anupam

Comment: What do you exactly understand by not working? What happens when you access domain.tld/file in your browser? What type of error do you get?

Comment: the domain name on which i installed whm/cpanel is not a registered domain name.
i installed on a random domain name "demo.demopanel.com".
can i access file from public html folder with domain name or ip, or i need a registered domain name ?  @BogdanStoica

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to access that URL in your browser you will have to manually edit your hosts file and add that domain with your server ip (since that domain/subdomain is not a real/registered domain). This way your computer will know where to make the connection. Since the domain does not actually exist then it's pretty logical to get an error.

So edit your computer hosts files and add something like this:

```
your_server_ip_address  demo.demopanel.com
```

Save the file and try refreshing the page in your browser.

On Linux/MacOSX your hosts file is located in `/etc/hosts`

On Windows your hosts file is locate in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Or use a real domain name, do the DNS settigs accordingly and try again!